# How to Add/Update shipping address of customer usnig REST Api in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to Add/Update/Delete shipping address of the specific customer (using auth token) using REST API in magento2. Is any API endpoint available for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get customer shipping address and delete it by using Magento 2 default rest API endpoints. You can check details here. `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/webapi.xml`

**To get shipping address by customer ID**

```
/V1/customers/:customerId/shippingAddress
```

**To delete shipping address by address id** (you should get the address id from above endpoint).

```
/V1/addresses/:addressId
```

So, if you want to **add** & **edit**, you should create a basic module where you can define custom endpoints and methods.

If you want to know how to create custom rest api in Magento 2 you can check this out.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282480/i-am-new-here-i-want-to-know-how-can-i-create-my-own-simple-api